# xamarin.forms package name with debugger

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

When i set package name to SmartScout.SmartScout20 in android, the app is running and i can use the debugger.

When i set the package name to com.xxxxx.smartscout - the package name in the google play store, i can't work with the debugger and the app isn't running at all.

the xamarin error is:

Android application is debugging.
The application could not be started. Ensure that the application has been installed to the target device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).

Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this project is set to Deploy for this configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to verify if the package name matches the one you set for GPStore.

If so, clean your solution and rebuild. Use the following `adb` comand to uninstall your app from your device:

`adb uninstall yourpackagename`

And then run your project.